# flutter cloud firestore error when building iOS

Tags: cocoa, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble with installing my app on an iOS platform.  This used to work no problem then yesterday it came up with this error

```
    Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A image_cropper
      M Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - file_picker
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_storage
      - flutter_secure_storage
      - fluttertoast
      - image_picker
      - url_launcher

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `file_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/file_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_secure_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_secure_storage/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_cropper` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_7_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.5.2/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.5.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.9.0/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_3_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.4.2/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_c_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/3.5.0/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_2_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.2.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.5.2/TOCropViewController.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.6.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.4.2/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/1.0.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_8_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.25.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_a_d_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/a/leveldb-library/1.22/leveldb-library.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_c_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/c/d/Protobuf/3.11.2/Protobuf.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/0.3.9011/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.4.2/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.2.1/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.5.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_e_3.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.3.1/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.2.2/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.1.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.1.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/0.0.9/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/0.0.9/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/0.0.9/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_1_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.26.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/0.3.901/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/0.3.901/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/0.3.901/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/0.3.901/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/3.4.0/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.0.4/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_6_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/6/0/FirebaseInstanceID/4.3.0/FirebaseInstanceID.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_3_b.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.2.1/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.1.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.0.4/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.21.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.21.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.21.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_8_8.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.5/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/6/0/FirebaseInstanceID/4.2.2/FirebaseInstanceID.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.3/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/c/d/Protobuf/3.9.0/Protobuf.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.3/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.3/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.3/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/7/FirebaseAuthInterop/1.0.0/FirebaseAuthInterop.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/a/leveldb-library/1.20/leveldb-library.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

    Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
      A BoringSSL-GRPC
      A Firebase
      A FirebaseAnalytics
      A FirebaseAuth
      A FirebaseAuthInterop
      A FirebaseCore
      A FirebaseFirestore
      A FirebaseInstanceID
      A FirebaseStorage
      A Flutter
      A GTMSessionFetcher
      A GoogleAppMeasurement
      A GoogleUtilities
      A Protobuf
      A TOCropViewController
      A cloud_firestore
      A file_picker
      A firebase_auth
      A firebase_core
      A firebase_storage
      A flutter_secure_storage
      A fluttertoast
      A gRPC-C++
      A gRPC-Core
      A image_cropper
      A image_picker
      A leveldb-library
      A nanopb
      A url_launcher

    Downloading dependencies

    -> Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
     > Git download
     > Git download
         $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/f2/cpx0475j7t52__99k3spzhn00000gp/T/d20200123-18474-a1ik9x --template=

    [!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
    [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/f2/cpx0475j7t52__99k3spzhn00000gp/T/d20200123-18474-a1ik9x --template=

    Cloning into '/var/folders/f2/cpx0475j7t52__99k3spzhn00000gp/T/d20200123-18474-a1ik9x'...
    error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
    fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: index-pack failed

    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:142:in `rescue in execute_command'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:139:in `execute_command'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:154:in `block in executable'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:79:in `block in clone'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:173:in `block in ui_sub_action'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:172:in `ui_sub_action'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:77:in `clone'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:45:in `download!'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:82:in `block in download'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:157:in `block in ui_action'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:156:in `ui_action'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.2.2/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in `download'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:108:in `download_source'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:75:in `download_request'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `download'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:154:in `block in uncached_pod'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in `in_tmpdir'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `uncached_pod'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:69:in `install!'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:557:in `install_source_of_pod'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:508:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:507:in `block in install_pod_sources'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in `each'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in `install_pod_sources'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:248:in `block in download_dependencies'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:247:in `download_dependencies'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:157:in `install!'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.8.4/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         Cloning into '/var/folders/f2/cpx0475j7t52__99k3spzhn00000gp/T/d20200123-18474-a1ik9x'...
         error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
         fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
         fatal: early EOF
         fatal: index-pack failed

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I have created a new project and linked it to firebase when I just use firebase_auth, firebase_storage the project loads fine as soon as I add cloud_firestore this error appears again.  I have also uncommented the version but that does not make a difference.  I also know that it is not my internet connection and have enabled Multidex.

this is my flutter doctor

```
Angela@Iains-iMac ~ % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I have added in

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and that does not make a difference.

This is the output I receive when it runs without cloud_firestore and it loads

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           32.3s
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...
    [C1.1 EBE42BCF-38C4-4D92-AB4C-EC599DF9215D 192.168.0.31:62925<->216.58.204.10:443]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    Duration: 240.325s, DNS @0.005s took 0.003s, TCP @0.014s took 0.174s, TLS took 0.101s
    bytes in/out: 4272/1478, packets in/out: 8/11, rtt: 0.110s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
    [C2.1 70BAEB95-E6C7-4AB7-B5E9-EB862B22E8FA 192.168.0.31:63765<->172.217.169.46:443]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    Duration: 0.314s, DNS @0.006s took 0.005s, TCP @0.020s took 0.031s, TLS took 0.123s
    bytes in/out: 4292/1048, packets in/out: 8/9, rtt: 0.040s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
    [C3.1 CD0C544B-715E-45E3-BEFB-7B7E3AE46F7F 192.168.0.31:63766<->172.217.169.46:443]
    Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
    Duration: 0.513s, DNS @0.000s took 0.002s, TCP @0.003s took 0.137s, TLS took 0.215s
    bytes in/out: 4245/1495, packets in/out: 8/10, rtt: 0.116s, retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
flutter clean
pod repo update
rm -rf  /ios/Pods
rm -f /ios/Podfile.lock
```

Comment: Can you add more detail here please - for example what this achieves and why?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same problem for a while now. I don't think the error is from Firestore. The flutter framework in your project has become corrupted. You will need to delete this folder `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` and then run `pod install`. A new folder will be generated and all should be fine

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `m1 device` maybe or should run with `arch -x86_64 pod install` i have similiar issue on last month and solved, but now i got this same problem against and i have try but didnt resolve against.